# Fixed content on top of jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to have a fixed div on top of a UI dialog while the rest of the content should scroll.

I've managed to fix that relative to the container with `position: fixed` without specifying `left` nor `top` but i'm not able to resize it properly: its width it's relative to its content and not to its parent.

[I've set up a fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/0q47nvtw/)

Is there a way to achieve this beside adding a javascript that resize it each time the dialog is resized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hafuzbxm/5/

> **position: sticky;**

> An element with `position: sticky;` is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

> A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

**CSS**

```
#infoDialogMessage {
  position: relative;
}

#fixthis {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#scrollthis {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the `sticky` property but not with `top: 0`. Nice work